# Why isn't light working?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, light

I'm new to Blender. I've got a scene, I downloaded from an Internet forum about a year ago, but light isn't working.

If I create a new file, add a mesh and shine a light on it I get light.

When I follow the same process in the scene I want to light the spotlight has no effect.

Any ideas?

[image]

[image: lighting panel]

Thanks to @Timaroberts it appears the scene is upside down or something.

When I move the lamp underneath the plane and rotate it the scene lights as expected.

[image]

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the lamp's settings panel?

Comment: @PGmath thanks for taking a look. I updated my answer with a screenshot. http://i.stack.imgur.com/0aYVt.png

Comment: If it is on layer one you need to turn layer one on  or move the light to layer one. The layers are represented by the grids at the bottom of the window. If a square is greyed out it is off.

Comment: Are the layers your light and mesh live on, both being rendered in the 'Render Layers' under the 'Scene Tab' in the 'Properties Panel'?

Comment: Did you create the light in Blender internal, or game? If so, it may not work in cycles. The same goes for materials.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I noticed if I move the lamp below my plane and rotate it to shine up it works as expected. It seems my scene is upside down or inverted or something...

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the energy settings of the lamp, in wireframe you won't see the lighting, and your rendered viewport looks normal for a single spot at default values. Change the lamp's *strength* to a higher value, or you may use a plane with an *emission* material and you will see your scene much more clearly.[image]

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. I added the emission plane and I got the same result until I moved it below my plane. Then I noticed if I move the lamp below my plane and rotate it to shine up it works as expected. It seems my scene is upside down or inverted or something...